# Unwanted sleeping processes

Tags: boot, services, process

Today I tried to speed up my computer disabling unwanted processes. In system monitor I can see there 150 processes. Almost all of them were sleeping but still consuming a little but memory.
I've checked many tutorials, how to disable unwanted processes (I have used sysv-rc-conf, boot-up manager, renamed services in /ect/rc*.d), but all of them are old and some files seems have been deprecated or renamed. After reboot, in system monitor there are still about 150 processes sleeping. What am I doing wrong, or maybe I do not understand something.
If it so, please explain me what is the need of these sleeping processes and why are not they running ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check System > Preferences > Startup Applications and make sure that applications only launch at start-up when you need them to.

2) If you notice that the processes are named after applications you have installed, check the Options, Preferences, or Settings menu's in those applications, and look for an option to turn off "start at log in".

3) Processes that are running that are not listed in the list above are usually system processes that are necessary to the normal function of your operating system. They are listed as "sleeping" because they are not currently active. They still need to be running though, in case they are needed.

4) If you absolutely cannot handle the number of processes running, try backing up your files and reinstalling your operating system. I can't say I've ever had to do this with Linux (it's more of a windows thing to be honest) but if you install a lot of applications and leave them running all the time then this might be some "spring cleaning" for you to consider.